# Search for partial key in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have the following dictionary,

```
d = {'foo': 1,
     'bar': 2,
     'baz:foo', 3,
     'baz:bar', 4
    }
```

and I want to find whether any 'baz' keys exist in the dict. I have the following, which works fine.

```
for key in d:
    if key.startswith('baz'):
        do_something()
        break
```

I would prefer something like the following:

```
if 'baz*' in d:
    do_something()
```

but I haven't been able to make it work.

Is there a better way to search for partial keys in a python dictionary?

Comment: I think your solution is best of a bad data structure, maybe a better dictionary structure would be like `{'baz':{'':2, 'foo':3, 'bar':4}}`

Comment: also you didn't properly format your dictionary in your post

Comment: <h1> Check if there is a key in the dictionary with a if</h1>

**Hi, I wish this is what you was looking for... see ya.**

 

    d = {'foo': 1,
         'bar': 2,
         'baz:foo': 3,
         'baz:bar': 4
         }
    
    
    if [k for k in d if k.startswith("bar")]:
        print("Ok, I found it")

>output

    Ok, I found it
    >>>